# How can I set no-cache for Swashbuckle swagger UI

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle

My website is running behind the CDN. If `Cache-Control` header is not set to `no-store,no-cache` the page would be cached by CDN. SwaggerUI & swagger.json gets everytime cached which is realy annoying. I don't see an option to set cache-control for swagger, as there is no such property responsible for this.

I can't apply filter settings, as this would affect only controllers, while swagger is served from middleware.

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(opt =>
{
    opt.Filters.Add(new ResponseCacheAttribute() {
        NoStore = true,
        Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None
    });
}
```